# Stop QNetworkRequest buffering entire request

Tags: c++, qt, networking

How can I stop QNetworkRequest from buffering the entire contents of a QIODevice during a put/post to an HTTPS connection? It works fine when posting to HTTP but HTTPS causes the entire file to be read into memory before the post starts.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported using the Qt classes. The reason is that Qt needs to know the total data length for the SSL headers. Chunked encoding is not supported from a send perspective. You can however roll your own - you'll need to create your own SSL header, then create your own chunks of SSL-encoded data.

I suggest you wrap this all up in your own class, so it's nicely re-usable (why not post it online?).

BTW, most of this information was taken from a recent thread on the [Qt-interest mailing list](http://lists.trolltech.com/mailman/listinfo/qt-interest) - a thread on the 30th September 2009 discussed this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may probably have more success with Qt 4.6. It has some bugfixes regarding that.